# Is there a workaround for template template arguments being invisible?

Tags: c++, c++20, template-templates

Consider the following code:

```
template<typename... Args1> 
constexpr size_t direct = sizeof... (Args1);

template<template<typename... Args1> typename A1> 
constexpr size_t nested = sizeof... (Args1); // compile error ☹️
```

Nested line does not compile since (I presume) `Args1` is a nested argument.

Is there a way to work around this in a non-intrusive way? By intrusive I mean modifying types passed, for example adding

`constexpr size_t sizeof_args = sizeof... (Args...);`

to each template passed to this template.

Note: I am fine with using C++20 concepts, but AFAIK they do not offer improvements in this space.

Comment: Do you want to use `nested<std::vector>` or `nested<std::vector<int>>`?

Comment: @Jarod42 not sure what the question is, what I originally wanted(before I reduced code to code in questions) is to compare the second template argument, for example std::array<float, 6> and std::array<int,6>  should return same,  std::map<int,int> std::unordered_map<double, int> should return same ...

Comment: `std::array` is special as it mixes type and non type template parameter. but templates can also have *"template template parameters"*, as `std::vector` is not a type, but `std::vector<int>` is. we might write traits for both cases. `std::vector` has 2 type parameters (`T` and a (defaulted) `Allocator`), `std::vector<int/*, std::allocator<int>*/>` has also 2 types. `std::tuple` has no fixed numbers of parameters, `std::tuple<int>` has one, `std::tuple<int, char>` has two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a primary variable template, and then specialize the variable template for template template parameters.

This allows you to explicitly name the template parameters of the template template parameter separately:

```
template<typename ...> 
constexpr size_t nested = -1; // any value will do, 
                              // but prefer one that is invalid for specializations

template<template<typename ...> typename A1, typename... Args1> 
                // name the parameters here  ^_______________^
constexpr size_t nested<A1<Args1...>> = sizeof...(Args1);
    // specialize here ^____________^
```

The concepts feature added in C++20 doesn't help in any way here, since there's nothing being constrained.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Gn9b8e).

Comment: yes, it should be size_t/int, I was reducing my original code and messed up

Comment: Mild offtopic, but do you know why the original problem exists? I mean your code is cool solution, but seems quite hard solution to relatively common problem that I would naively expect to be solved by just making nested template arguments visible.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl It was just never specified that way. I'm not sure there's any *fundamental* reason for not allowing those parameters to be named. I think there's a question about *why* that has been asked before on SO; I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: It’s meaningless to make them “visible”: in the version in the question, you can write `nested<std::tuple>`, and what should the value be?